# C# Linq GroupBy Return Default Value Instead Of Null

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have the following list. I'm trying to split it into odd & even lists using `GroupBy`:

```
var x = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };

var y = x
  .GroupBy(x => x % 2 == 0)
  .Select(x => x.ToList())
  .ToList();
```

This outputs a `List<List<int>>`, the problem is that it doesn't insert null groups into the list, so the list has only 1 item in it.

I'd like for the absent values to be inserted as an *empty list*, so that when I do:

```
var odds = y[1] // => empty list instead of out of range
```

I tried doing the following:

```
var y = x
  .GroupBy(x => x % 2 == 0)
  .Select(x => x.ToList() ?? new List<int>())
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using `GroupJoin`; we form all required groups' keys with `Enumerable.Range(0, 2)` and then join `x` to them:

```
var x = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };

var y = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 2)
  .GroupJoin(x, 
             a => a, 
             b => b % 2, 
            (key, items) => (key : key, list : items.ToList()))
  .ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/YpiBfm

Comment: I was just about to post a similar answer: `Enumerable.Range(0, 2).ToDictionary(key => key, key => x.Where(value => value % 2 == key).ToList())`. Your 'GroupJoin' solution looks more elegant and is probably more efficient than iterating the values multiple times

Comment: This does solve the problem. However, I'd still prefer a GroupBy solution to avoid using Enumerable.Range (which isn't always straightforward)

Comment: @Preem Palver2: Willy-nilly you have to get *all* the groups' keys (you can't derive them from `x` since some values - like `1` in your example - can be absent and you don't know which ones). Technically you can have `Range(...).Join(...).GroupBy(...)` by why should we split `GroupJoin` into two operations?